# How to Call the method from the console to see that it works

Tags: javascript, jquery, console

I am able to call a id using following code .
My code for id as following:

```
<input id="movies" name="movies" type="text" value="new@gmail.com">
```

solution  it work's.

```
console.log($('#movies').val());
```

How to call same  for a method/function in console.

I am trying this

```
console.log(movies.countmovies().val()) ;
```

but getting following error.

> Uncaught TypeError: movies.countmovies is not a function(…)

Comment: What you expect `movies.countmovies().val()` to return ?

Comment: i am excepting movies.countmovies().val() return the number of  movies

Answer (score 0):

how do you declare your function?

you can use javascript patterns to tests your functions.

enter code here example :
in global scope

```
var movies = (function(){
   return {
        countMovies : function(){
        // your code goes here

        console.log('my movies');
       }

   }

   })()
```

in this way you can

```
    console.log(movies.countMovies()) // print: my movies
```

in your browser